# SpriteNode not rendered at first time when using atlases - works with xcassets

Tags: swift, xcode7, skspritenode, xcasset

I have a very strange behaviour when rendering SKSpriteNodes using an atlas via imageNamed.

```
sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: triangle.triangleType1.spriteName)
sprite.size.height = TileHeight
sprite.size.width = TileWidth
sprite.zRotation = DegreesToRadians(triangle.rotation)
sprite.position = pointForColumn(triangle.column, row:triangle.row, columnOffset: TileWidth, rowOffset: TileHeight, tw: TileWidth,th: TileHeight)
triangleLayer.addChild(sprite)
triangle.sprite1 = sprite
addedTriangles++

print(sprite)
```

Some of those Sprites are not rendered adding them to the layer (another SKSpriteNode) for first time - printing the "sprite" shows that they're size 0,0 and the image shows "*TrViolet*" instead of "*TrViolet@2x.png*".
Other ones are rendered as they supposed to be.

Removing all the nodes and executing the same code for a second time DOES work though.

When I put the image in xcassets it works like a charm - even for the first time.

Is there any way to debug this kind of behavior or you have any idea on what might be happening here?